# many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Why does one of the following code snippet always triggers this error (many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop) but the other don't.

This code works fine

```
const Admin = () => {
  const { adminId } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
    
  let studentEnglishResults: { [key: string]: string } = {};
  let englishResults: string[] = [];


  if (localStorage.length > 0) {

    studentEnglishResults = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem("englishAnswers") as string
    );
    englishResults = Object.keys(studentEnglishResults);
      } else {
  }

  const adminUser = adminUsers.find(
    (adminUser) => adminUser.adminId === adminId
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (adminUser?.adminId !== adminId) {
      navigate("/");
    }
  }, []);

  const clearResult = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
  };

  const backToLogin = () => {
    navigate("/");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="bg-gray-400 mx-auto w-3/4 p-3 mt-5">
        <p className="capitalize font-serif">
          <span className="font-bold">Admin</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="my-10 flex justify-center gap-3 text-white">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn bg-green-500"
          onClick={clearResult}
        >
          Generate Results
        </button>

        <button type="button" className="btn bg-red-600" onClick={clearResult}>
          Clear Results
        </button>

        <button type="button" className="btn bg-blue-500" onClick={backToLogin}>
          Login
        </button>
      </div>

      <div className="shadow-md shadow-gray-500 w-2/4 mx-auto p-5">
        <p className="text-2xl text-gray-500">
          Answers Selected by the Student
        </p>
        <table className="table-auto border-collapse border w-full">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className="text-left">Question</th>
              <th className="text-left">Answer</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {englishResults.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td className="">{item}</td>
                  <td>{studentEnglishResults[item]}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Admin;
```

But this always triggers error (many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop).

```
  const Admin = () => {
  const { adminId } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [results, setResults] = useState(false);
  const [studentEnglishResults, setStudentEnglishResults] = useState<{
  [key: string]: string;
  }>({});
  const [englishResults, setEnglishResults] = useState<string[]>([]);

  if (localStorage.length > 0) {  
setResult(true)
    setStudentResults(JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem("englishAnswers") as string
    );
setEnglishResults(Object.keys(studentEnglishResults));
   
  } else {
setResult(false)
  }

  const adminUser = adminUsers.find(
    (adminUser) => adminUser.adminId === adminId
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (adminUser?.adminId !== adminId) {
      navigate("/");
    }
  }, []);

  const clearResult = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
  };

  const backToLogin = () => {
    navigate("/");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="bg-gray-400 mx-auto w-3/4 p-3 mt-5">
        <p className="capitalize font-serif">
          <span className="font-bold">Admin</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="my-10 flex justify-center gap-3 text-white">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn bg-green-500"
          onClick={clearResult}
        >
          Generate Results
        </button>

        <button type="button" className="btn bg-red-600" onClick={clearResult}>
          Clear Results
        </button>

        <button type="button" className="btn bg-blue-500" onClick={backToLogin}>
          Login
        </button>
      </div>

      <div className="shadow-md shadow-gray-500 w-2/4 mx-auto p-5">
        <p className="text-2xl text-gray-500">
          Answers Selected by the Student
        </p>
        <table className="table-auto border-collapse border w-full">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className="text-left">Question</th>
              <th className="text-left">Answer</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {englishResults.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td className="">{item}</td>
                  <td>{studentEnglishResults[item]}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Admin;
```

The difference is the second snippet used `useState` hook to set the values while the first uses normal variable.

Does this mean using `useState` to set values is a bad idea. I heard it was encouraged to always use `useState` to set variables. How do I avoid this error then?

Than you.

Comment: The second example: the component renders, you set state, component re-renders, you set state triggering another render etc.

Comment: You should put your if statement with localstorage in a useEffect

Comment: setState triggers rerenders. It re-renders, it sets the state again...